# Exception when trying to run Word Automation Services in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, word-automation-service

I try to convert a docx-file to pdf by using the following simple Code:

```
ConversionJobSettings jobSettings = new ConversionJobSettings();
jobSettings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
ConversionJob job = new ConversionJob("Word Automation Services", jobSettings);
job.AddFile(path + docFilename, path + pdfFilename);
job.Start();
```

But when I try to run the code I get an exception:

> A Word Automation Services application proxy with name 'Word Automation Services'
>   cannot be found

In the service applications, both

> Word Automation Services

and

> Word Automation Services Proxy

are started.

I use Microsoft.Word.Office.Server (from C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI)

(UPDATE:) It does seem to work when I add my own proxy and use that name, but that should not be necessary, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following snippet:

```
 WordServiceApplicationProxy proxy =
                            (WordServiceApplicationProxy)
                                SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Site)
                                    .GetDefaultProxy(typeof (WordServiceApplicationProxy));

                        ConversionJob job = new ConversionJob(proxy); //, jobSettings);
```

Seems like my proxy is not called "Word Automation Services", but "Word Automation Services Application"

Like that approach even more, no "magic strings"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the proxy name "Word Automation Services Proxy" in the `ConversionJob` constructor:

```
ConversionJobSettings jobSettings = new ConversionJobSettings();
jobSettings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
ConversionJob job = new ConversionJob("Word Automation Services Proxy", jobSettings);
job.AddFile(path + docFilename, path + pdfFilename);
job.Start();
```

Comment: Nope. Did not work. (And all MSDN-Examples don't use "Proxy" either)

Answer (score 0):

Central Administration -> Application Management   -> Configure service application associations ->

check if the Application Proxy Group asociated to your web application has the "Word Automation Service", if not add him to Application Proxies

[image]